# webpack-hot-middleware not working with webpack-dev-middleware

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware

I'm trying to use webpack-hot-middleware to hot reload the modules of my application. I'm using webpack-dev-middleware as well.

Here is my setup.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dev-front-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.production.js",
    "clean-dist": "rimraf dist",
    "lint": "esw buildScripts data/*.js src *.js --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist",
    "prestart": "babel-node buildScripts/startMessage.js",
    "security-check": "nsp check",
    "serve-dist": "babel-node buildScripts/distServer.js",
    "serve-src": "babel-node buildScripts/srcServer.js",
    "share": "ngrok http 3000",
    "start": "npm run serve-src",
    "test": "babel-node buildScripts/testSetup.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.11",
    "angular-animate": "<1.6.0",
    "angular-aria": "<1.6.0",
    "angular-audio": "^1.7.3",
    "angular-cookie": "^4.1.0",
    "angular-cookies": "<1.6.0",
    "angular-google-maps": "^2.4.1",
    "angular-ismobile": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "^0.9.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-messages": "<1.6.0",
    "angular-scroll": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-socialshare": "^2.3.7",
    "angular-socket-io": "^0.7.0",
    "angular-timeago": "^0.4.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "angulartics": "^1.4.0",
    "angulartics-google-analytics": "^0.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "cropperjs": "^0.8.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "ng-infinite-scroll": "^1.3.0",
    "ng-token-auth": "^0.0.30",
    "ngSmoothScroll": "^2.0.0",
    "ngclipboard": "^1.1.1",
    "restangular": "^1.6.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "author": "Medhavin Goyal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "ngrok": "^2.2.11",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "strip-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var VENDOR_LIBS = [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?timeout=20000&reload=true',
    'angular',
    'angular-animate',
    'angular-aria',
    'angular-audio',
    'angular-cookie',
    'angular-cookies',
    'angular-google-maps',
    'angular-ismobile',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'angular-material',
    'angular-messages',
    'angular-scroll',
    'angular-socialshare',
    'angular-socket-io',
    'angular-timeago',
    'angular-ui-router',
    'angulartics',
    'angulartics-google-analytics',
    'bootstrap',
    'cropperjs',
    'lodash',
    'ng-file-upload',
    'ng-infinite-scroll',
    'ng-token-auth',
    'ngSmoothScroll',
    'ngclipboard',
    'restangular',
    'socket.io-client'
];

const config =  {
    entry: {
        bundle: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?timeout=20000&reload=true', './src/app.module.js'],
        vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                use: 'url-loader',
                test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/
            },
            {
                use: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]',
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/
            },
            {
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader'
                }),
                test: /\.css$/
            },
            {
                use: 'raw-loader',
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/style.[hash].css'),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['vendor','manifest']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Tether: 'tether',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            _: 'lodash',
            io: 'socket.io-client'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'assets',
            to: 'assets'
        }]),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        // new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    target: 'web'
};

module.exports = config;
```

**srcServer.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback';
import config from '../webpack.config';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(config), {
    noInfo: false,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(webpack(config), {
   'log': console.log,
   'heartbeat': 10 * 1000
}));
app.use(historyApiFallback({
    disableDotRule: true
}));
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(config), {
    noInfo: false,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("App listening on port " + port);
    }
});
```

The setup is not working. The compilation works fine when I update my code, and when I refresh my browser, the new application code is executed. However the modules aren't replaced.

[Output in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDoPj.png)

[Network Traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TfAW.jpg)

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you follow the instructions in [the fine manual](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage), which in your case would translate to something like this:

```
let compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo     : false,
  publicPath : config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  'log'       : console.log,
  'path'      : '/__webpack_hmr',
  'heartbeat' : 10 * 1000
}));
```

I'm not sure about the various options that you're passing to `webpackHotMiddleware` (`log` already defaults to `console.log` so you can leave it out, and you should probably use the default for `path` instead of setting it yourself).

Comment: Thank you robertkelp. I am following the manual, but in vain. It's just not working.

Comment: Did you remove the `path` option?

Comment: Yes. Did that too. Still the exact same issue.

Comment: Can you update your question to the code that you now have?

Comment: You are including `webpackMiddleware` twice, and you're not using a shared compiler but creating a new one for each middleware. Please read the documentation _carefully_.